# Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting the following java compiler errors:

```
main.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method parseInt(int)
location: class java.lang.Integer
        int count = Integer.parseInt(getPennies());
                           ^
main.java:23: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pennies do you have?");
                                       ^
```

2 errors

Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;

class main {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        int count = Integer.parseInt(getPennies());
        System.out.println("You have "+count+" pennies");

    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {

        System.out.println("Please insert a number");
        getPennies();
    }
}


public static int getPennies() {

    int input = 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pennies do you have?");

    return input;
}
}
```

Any idea why I am getting these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `getPennies()` returns an `int`, and there's no such method as `Integer.parseInt(int)` - the idea is that `parseInt` parses a string and *gives* you an integer.

Then later you have:

```
 int input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pennies do you have?");
```

... but showInputDialog returns a string, not an integer.

You could fix both of these problems by changing getPennis() like this:

```
public static String getPennies() {
  return JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pennies do you have?");
}
```

Or:

```
public static int getPennies() {
  String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pennies do you have?");
  return Integer.parseInt(text);
}
```

and removing the call to `Integer.parseInt` from the *caller* of `getPennies()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt` requires a `String` input, not an `int`. Just use `getPennies()` without it. For the second error, `showInputDialog` returns a `String`, so use the `parseInt` function there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `parseInt()` method parses a string to an integer, the input is done as a string, so changing the return type of `getPennies()` to a `String` will probably do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The method `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns a `String` and not an `int`.

So you have a type incompatibility issue.